# AngularJS: Absolute vs Relative Paths

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm starting an AngularJS application and I need to call my static files with an absolute path in production mode and with a relative path in development.

If for example I need to access a JS static folder, in production I'll need to call: https://statics.domain.com/js and in development I'll have a regular `assets/js` folder.

Is there a best approach for that?

Thanks!

Edit: An important note is that this app is separated from the backend.

Comment: Build processes can handle this, though, i'd prefer to have production run using relative paths too where possible.

Comment: Why would relative paths in production be better?

Comment: I never said it would be better, just that i prefer it. I find it makes deployment easier.

Comment: In my current application i use a build process that has two different entry points: Build for development, and Build for production. Based on which build i'm running, it outputs different target api endpoints in the resulting code.

Comment: In one application I've done exactly that. But a requirement for this new one is that the statics would be in a CDN in production. And in development we could access them in assets/ folder

Comment: Gotcha. Then you can do the exact same thing for your index.html. One build process copies it as is with relative paths to the public folder, and the other does the same but replaces the relative paths with absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Base Tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) to set the base path for all relative URLs.

So you could have  in development and change that base href to static.domain.com in production.

However, the base tag is a bit obscure and I wouldn't recommend it for serious work.

Other ideas:

Could you use your hosts file to redirect static.testdomain.com to your local environment.

Could you use an environment variable or other configuration setting to alter the javascript references.

Comment: Some people hate w3schools as a source of information, you might want to add something like MDN or even the spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata#the-base-element

Comment: Sure @Tibos, I've edited to be MDN. (I find MDN more readable)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to have your server serve different index.html files depending on the environment (production versus development). If you don't use a server at the moment you could consider a lightweight NodeJS one.

You could even use a templating engine (ex Express + Jade) and have the same index.html file be constructed differently based in the environment.

Comment: The application should be separated from the backend, just an AngularJS application by itself that communicates with REST with the back-end

Comment: @MatheusLima Your client needs to get the application from a server. That is not necessarily the backend of the application, but it is still something that serves assets.